# What are good public datasets for time series analysis with “certified” (by papers in the literature) good predictors of the target variable?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictor-importance

I have to test different models for time series forecasting and predictors (exogenous covariates) goodness evaluation and I would like to use datasets used in relevant scientific publications that have "certified" the goodness of some predictor variables (of the target variable), so I can compare the results and try to refine my models.

Comment: I don't know how strict of a definition you are using to define a "certified" dataset, but the most obvious starting point is Kaggle. Quite a few are from academic sources, though a publication may not always be tied to them.